# Jquery changing attributes using loop

Tags: jquery, each, attr

If I have the following variables:

```
var ordercode, ordername, order1price, orderfree;
```

How can I add the values of these variables to attr[value] using 'each'?

```
<form>
   <input type="hidden" name="ordercode" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="ordername" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="order1price" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="orderfree" value="">
</form>
```

Like:

```
$('form input').each(function {
    value = ordercode where name = ordercode
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: you only want to change the value of ordercode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easy does it:

```
$('form input').each(function {
    $(this).val($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You can't access variables like that...

what you can do is to create an object with those input names as keys like

```js
var obj = {
  ordercode: 'ordercode',
  ordername: 'ordername',
  order1price: 'order1price',
  orderfree: undefined
}
$('form input').val(function() {
  return obj[this.name];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="ordercode" value="">
  <input type="text" name="ordername" value="">
  <input type="text" name="order1price" value="">
  <input type="text" name="orderfree" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form input').each(function() {
    if (this.name == 'ordercode'){
        this.value = 'ordercode';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this keyword

```
value=$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of a particluar input, use like this

```
$("input[name='ordercode']").val("new value");
```